# What's N900 wireless?

Tags: wireless-networking, router

I'm trying to buy a new router and I'm seeing N600, N750, and N900.

What are these? Do they make a big difference?

Comment: What make when i tpe N900 it shows me a nokia. Is it for home? are you a gamer or just for normal stuff? what type of internet do you have? might help if you put down some more details so we can give you a proper answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a way of specifying the transmission bandwidth depending on which frequency bands are used, how many bands are available, and how many streams are offered.

- N600 routers use dual-band 2.4 GHz, with a bandwidth of 2×300Mbps = 600 Mbps
- N750 routers use 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz, with a bandwidth of 1×300Mbps and 1×450Mbps = 750 Mbps
- N900 routers use dual-band 5 GHz, with a bandwidth of 2×450Mbps = 900 Mbps

Naturally, you could also imagine other combinations. See also:

- [What is the difference in all the wireless N speeds?](http://nerdblog.londondrugs.com/what-is-the-difference-in-all-the-wireless-n-speeds)
- [What is the difference between 5 Ghz and 2.4 Ghz router settings?](http://ldnerdblog.blogspot.ca/2012/02/what-is-difference-between-5-ghz-and-24.html)
- [IEEE 802.11n-2009](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/802.11n)

Comment: I am pretty sure that all dual-band routers are 5Ghz and 2.4Ghz, and it is the antenna array that dictates how much you can push through them.  So a dual-band N600 would be 300mbps through each band.